# How to convert WCF service to REST with Dynamic Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, windows-phone-8.1

I have called WSDL service from Java with using WEB REFERENCE named "eps".
Now I have created WCF service with that "Webreference" and Response is in the form of "XML",
and everytime the Response will be dynamic.
Everything works well, now I have to call WCF service to Windows Phone 8.1 with REST endpoints.
I am done with "web.config" file, My problem is that
"How does the service get parameters?"

see my code below:

```
[DataContract]     
public string login(string uname, string pwd)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(eps.m12345(uname,pwd));
    string connection = Convert.ToString(doc);
    return connection;
}
```

How do I enable to allow client to enter "Username" and "Password".This is the main issue.

Here is my OperationContract:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
UriTemplate = "live_login?uname={uname}&pwd={pwd}")]
string login(string uname, string pwd);
```

In this case, it is working for Static response:

```
[DataContract]
public string login()
{
    return "ABC";
}

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",UriTemplate = "login")]
```

This below code I have called in Windows Phone 8.1

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:xxxx/xxxxxxxxx.svc/login");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var dialog = new MessageDialog(data);
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: Have you tried to use HttpClient? Your url is like your UriTemplate.

Comment: @L.B yes, I am done with static response, but how to do with dynamic response and parameters, when I run service,it is not asking for parameters thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by static/dynamic response? Can explain it with examples in your question, also post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @L.B ok, in normal WCF service, when I run it, its asking for parameters and "Invoke", after converting to REST, I am not getting to enter parameters. Do you know about this issue?

Comment: @L.B See my edited code. I have explained with static example.

Comment: I still don't see any code of your *client*

Comment: `var h = new HttpClient(); var response = await h.GetStringAsync("http://server/live_login?uname=john&pwd=doe");` that is all.

Comment: @L.B ok, see my last edit, I saw your last comment, thank you brother, but what about changing data?